# What is the name and formula for this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can't figure out what this problem is but I have the solution.
The Equation:
Find all real solutions

$\frac{-15}{(4x+1)}+4 = x$

Solution is $1,\frac{11}{4}$

What is this type of equation called and what is the formula associated with it? (bonus points if you notice anything different about the other problems)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z0mp.jpg)

Comment: It's quadratic equation.  Welcome to MathSE.  You can wiki the associated formula.

Comment: it seems to be different than the quadratic formula im used to. -b +- b^2 -4ac

Comment: By multiplying both sides by the denominator $4x+1$, they are actually the *same* except at $x=\frac14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure to solve your question is the following:

$$\frac{-15}{4x+1}+4 = x \Rightarrow \frac{-15}{4x+1}+\frac{4(4x+1)}{4x+1} = \frac{x(4x+1)}{(4x+1)} =$$

$$\frac{16x-11}{4x+1} = \frac{4x^2 + x}{4x+1} \Rightarrow \frac{-4x^2+15x-11}{4x+1} = 0$$

$$-4x^2+15x-11 = 0 \Rightarrow \{x_1=1, x_2=\frac{11}{4}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both sides of the equation by $(4x+1)$, we get:

$$-15 + 4(4x+1) = x(4x+1).$$

By distributing, moving everything to one side, and combining like terms; this equation becomes:

$$4x^2 -15x + 11 = 0.$$

---

The quadratic formula is a formula for the solutions to an equation of the form $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0.$$

The solutions are $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}_.$$

---

Therefore the solutions to the equation you had were:

$$ x = \frac{15 \pm \sqrt{15^2 - 4(4)(11)}}{2(4)}$$

If you simplify that expression, you get $x = 1$ and $x=\frac{11}{4}$.

---

Note that $x = -\frac{1}{4}$ needs to be excluded from possible solutions since you are dividing by $4x+1$ in the original equation. In this problem, it doesn't matter. But if $-\frac{1}{4}$ had shown up as a solution, we would have to disregard it.

Answer (score 0):

No name in particular that I recall of. Perhaps "with fractions" or "rational"? It really depends on how your country's board of education names the school programs. Typically, you write down the conditions that allow the whole expression to exist (in this case, all denominators $\ne0$) and then proceed to multiply both sides by the least common denominator. Once you've done it, you put everything on one side and you'll end up with something like $ax^2+bx+c=0$. You pick the solution(s) of the latter which **also** satisfy the aforementioned "$\text{denominators}\ne0$" condition.

Having a formula for this is kinda pointless: people typically just practice the procedure over and over until they master it. Of course, one could write explicitly a "formula" to deal with things like $$\frac{1}{bx+c}=dx+e\\\left(\text{btw, something like} \begin{cases}x=\frac{-be-cd\pm\sqrt{b^2e^2+d^2c^2+2bedc-4cd+4}}{2db}\\ x\ne -\frac cb\\ b,d\ne0\end{cases},\text{ but I might be wrong}\right)$$ but it'd have a number of cases to keep in mind, and ultimately the formula would not help you dealing with similar problems like $$\frac{a}{bx+c}+\frac{d}{ex+f}=h$$

At this point, it's more helpful for students learning to do the elementary algebraic manipulation that allow you to reduce a complicated problem to an easier one.

In your worksheets there are some equations "with radicals".